# How to attach JWT authorization header to Server Sent Events (using EventSource)?

Tags: reactjs, server-sent-events

I have a React webapp that uses an `EventSource`. I'd like to add authentication/authorization to the backend API endpoint that it hits. How do I attach the following header to the `EventSource`?

```
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${authSession.access_token}`
    },
```

Comment: did you fixed this issue? @Rylan Schaeffer

Answer (score 0):

I found this library:

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sse`

It simplifies attaching `jwt token` to the event source.

Right now I'm working on refreshing the token using event source.

I'll update the answer if I can find something useful.

Comment: did you finished your minimal demo? @Kirill